# Problema al imprimir en impresora matricial con papel continuo en Java

Tags: java

Estoy imprimiendo cheques con una aplicación Java, hago uso de `DocPrintJob` para crear el documento que imprimo.

La impresión la hace bien en la primer página. El problema surge cuando continúa a la siguiente página ya que como la impresora es alimentada con papel continuo(papel perforado) que es halado por el tractor; al continuar con la segunda y las siguientes páginas, la impresión comienza en una posición cada vez más abajo.

¿Puede alguien ayudarme a resolver mi problema?. Siento que es cuestión del tamaño de la página a imprimir, que no sé como definirlo. En el código yo defino un tamaño, pero veo que no lo respeta.

Aquí mi código:

```
InputStream ff = new ByteArrayInputStream(strLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
pras.add(new Copies(1));
pras.add(new JobName("rptCheque", locale));
pras.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
pras.add(new MediaPrintableArea(3, 3, 173, 218, MediaPrintableArea.MM));

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(ff, flavor, null);
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

job.print(doc, pras);
pjw.waitForDone();
```

Esa es la parte que define la impresión.

Comment: Hace mucho tiempo pasado había reportes de que `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE` ignora los atributos del `PrintRequestAttributeSet`. Si me recuerdo bien, la solución era de guardar el documento en formato pdf y ejecutar un servicio externo para imprimir (creo que fue en perl). Quizás vale la pena investigar por estos lados.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero ¿no habrá forma de hacerlo con este código? con algún cambio.

Comment: Es posible que lo hay, pero no he trabajado con impresión directo desde Java hace mucho tiempo, así desconozco el estado en que están las bibliotecas. En los casos en que tuve que imprimir,  se enviaban documentos a un servidor de impresión. Solo compartí contigo algo de que me recordé por coincidencia, te recomiendo verificarlo como es actualmente. Puede ser que simplemente otro `DocFlavor` te sirve.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.